# Select box option-list appears off the page in Chrome

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have created a `select` list using PHP, and when clicking on it to select an option from the drop down the option list jumps to the top of the page showing about 3 options, and the rest are off the page.

It only happens in Chrome. Is there a way to fix this using CSS?

Here's the relevant code:

#### HTML

```html
<tr>
    <td><label>Manufacturer</label></td>
    <td>
        <select id="prodManufacturer" class="validate[required]" name="prodManufacturer">
            <?php foreach($aAllManufacturer as $aManufacturer){ ?> 
                <option value="<?php echo $aManufacturer['prod_manufacturer_id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $aManufacturer['prod_manufacturer_name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### CSS

```css
#productFormContentWrapper select {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #9d1116;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Can you throw some code at us to help look into the problem?  Any CSS that affects the select box / its container would be helpful.

Comment: @Stephen Sorry for the late reply i've added some code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I think a screenshot might be more helpful. If I understand the problem correctly, it might just be a browser bug, and nothing you have control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mozilla Developer Network:

> If the control is presented as a scrolled list box, this attribute
>   represents the number of rows in the list that should be visible at
>   one time. **Browsers are not required to present a select elements as a
>   scrolled list box.**

Simply omit the `size` attribute or set its value to `0` (or `1`, if following the HTML5 specs, but this apparently causes legacy issues, so avoid it for now).

See a live **[demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuqAG/2/)**.

**References:**

- [`select` element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select)