# Styling a select box with a size attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the life of me I can't figure out how to style a select box that uses the size attribute. Almost all of the tutorials out there are for a single-item select box. Does anybody have any experience with select boxes that use the size attribute?

For reference, this is what I'm talking about:

```
<select class="awesome_select" size="5">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

I'm developing on Chrome/Safari/Firefox for Mac. I have tried the -moz-appearance: none; and -webkit-appeareance: none; properties for both the select box and the individual options. I have also tried setting a border on the select and the options.

I am able to style the select box in the sense that I can resize it, move it around, and change the font size, but I am completely unable to style the individual options.

*edit 1* Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
select.awesome_select {
border: 1px solid #ACADAC;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
-webkit-appeareance: none;
}
select.awesome_select option {
padding: 5px;
background-color: #FF0000;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

If I have a regular select (without using the size attribute) I can style this however I'd like. WITH the size attribute, the options suddenly are not able to be modified in any way.

Comment: What kind of style are u trying to apply? there's very limited you can do to SELECT element comparing to "real" DOM elements.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I was typing in the tags and pressed Enter by mistake and submitted the question way sooner than I was ready. I'd like to start by changing the padding and highlight color of the select options.

Comment: Yup, I believe options don't have this level of control. You may have to use a custom (e.g. jQuery) control

Comment: Are you aware of any existing jQuery plugins that create a customizable list based off a select using the size attribute? Pretty much everything I find only works with dropdowns.

Comment: I've posted answer with my suggestion.

Comment: Is this a multiselect box? If so, you should also use the `multiple` attribute. Otherwise, I don't think the `size` attribute does anything.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 maybe just visuals.

Comment: Drop that `size` attribute. See [a related post of mine here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10831016/547020).

Comment: The way my page works is that I have two selects adjacent to each other. The first one determines the options present in the second one. To have them both be dropdowns is visually offensive to me, so I have elected to have the second one be a listbox for the visual effect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're open to use jQuery and since original SELECT doesn't suit your need, I suggest using [Selectable from jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/)

If this doesn't suit you, Google for others, but search for "listbox" (e.g. "jQuery listbox), you will find alternatives like http://kalnitsky.org/projects/listbox.js/en/.

Most of them won't convert your existing SELECT element into a new one, but there're some that would.

Comment: Not a fan of Selectable as it would force me to rewrite things to be lists instead of selects. Listbox.js is good in that it lets me retain selects, but its support of navigating by keystroke is really awful. Thanks for the tip about using the search term "listbox".

Comment: I'm going to mark this as an answer since it seems like what I'm looking to do doesn't exist or isn't possible. Thanks for the suggestion - I'll probably end up rewriting Listbox.js for better performance.

Comment: @boneyjellyfish thanks I appreciate it. I did put some research into this and it looks like the only alternative

Answer (score 1):

give a class to the select element and do your css there.

```
<select class="classname" size="5">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

//css

```
.classname {width:0;
height:0;
background:# ;//etc }
```

Comment: My actual markup uses a class. I accidentally submitted the question before it was ready and had to edit it as quickly as I could.

Comment: Then give styles to your <option>
but i think only some properties was working

Comment: ya, padding, height, margin , width all are not affecting

Comment: @YuriyGalanter You seem to spend a lot of time telling people what will not work. You must be very clever.